# Run a python script from terminal with a source root folder set in the IDE

Tags: python

I'm getting this error when trying to run a script from the terminal:
`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'src'`

Here is the setup:

Terminal

```
python -m file.py
```

Project:

```
my-proj/src/file.py
my-proj/src/helper.py
```

```
#file.py

from helper import some_tool

def run():
    some_tool()

if __name__ = "__main__"
    run()
```

Comment: just import like this `from helper import some_tool` and run wihtout -m option like `python file.py`

Answer (score 0):

Since you are working from the src folder you should not need to reference it in your import.

It should be:

```
from helper import some_tool
```

Comment: good point. File.py is actually in a subfolder. I will change that. I think this is path issue.